# How to find all Network Interfaces for a given ip address

Tags: c#, .net

How to find all Network Interfaces for a given ip address.

Right now,I am using below code to determine it but it is always giving it for local computer and I want to achieve it for given IP address.

```
NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
{

    IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
    IPAddressCollection dnsServers = adapterProperties.DnsAddresses;
    if (dnsServers.Count > 0)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Adapter Id .... : " + adapter.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Adapter Description .... : " + adapter.Description);
        Console.WriteLine("Adapter Name .... : " + adapter.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Network Interface Type .... : " + adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Adapter Speed .... : " + adapter.Speed);
        Console.WriteLine("OperationalStatus .... : " + adapter.OperationalStatus);
        Console.WriteLine("Adapter SupportsMulticast .... : " + adapter.SupportsMulticast);

        }
    }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Well obviously it only works for the local machine - you're asking for NICes of the local machine. Why do you want to know the NICes of a remote computer?

Comment: (this question isn't really a duplicate - it doesn't ask for NICes on the local computer)

Comment: Use WMI queries to query data like this from remote machines.

Comment: Hi Sean, I am using WMI queries to achieve it but most of property values are coming for corresponding key.